# Angular Router: How to handle delegation to submodule's router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Can you please advice me how to handle the situation where I have in a high level component `router-outlet` and in its sub component another `router-outlet`?

It seems to me that in this scenario I need to have the sub component in its own module and to provide for it its own router using the `RouterModule.forChild`. After the configuration I can display the main component on `localhost:4200/main`, but I get this error when going to `localhost:4200/main/section`:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/section'
```

I have in the app.component.html:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In this `app.component.html` I want to display `MainViewComponent` under `localhost:4200/main`

This MainViewComponent component is in its own module has its own logic to display its subcomponents in its `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and should be accessible through an url like `localhost:4200/main/section`, `localhost:4200/main/section2`.

**app/app-routing.module.ts (imported by app.module.ts )**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainViewComponent } from './main-view-module/main-view/main-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'main', component: MainViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app/main-view-module/app-routing.module.ts (imported by app/main-view-module/main-view.module.ts)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SectionViewComponent }      from './main-view-module/section-view.component';
import { Section2ViewComponent }      from './main-view-module/section2-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'section', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'section', component: SectionViewComponent },
  { path: 'section2', component: Section2ViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After additional research:

The feature that I look for is called [Lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#asynchronous-routing).

In order to make my example work I just had to add `loadChildren` property to the `path` in my `app/app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'main', component: MainViewComponent,
        loadChildren: 'app/main-view-module/main-view.module#MainViewModule'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place all routes in one place preferably, and when 1 component `router-outlet`

exists in another component u can do this

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'main', component: MainViewComponent, children: [
       { path: '', redirectTo: 'section', pathMatch: 'full' },
       { path: 'section', component: SectionViewComponent },
       { path: 'section2', component: Section2ViewComponent }
    ]}
];
```

In other case that components will just change 1 another (talking about placing routes like you do, but in 1 place)

Actually all your modules are imported to `app.module`, modules are more for code abstraction, so you can build routes hierarchy in one place, nothing should go wrong. At this point, using `children` option you are like saying, i want this component to exist when i am on child routes.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I was not sure when to exactly use the `children` and now it is clear, also it helped me to find solution for my case where I actually prefer to hide the mapping in the module. I will post it later in my own answer.